# why intellij new configuration button disabled?

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration

I want to add a new setting but the + button is disabled.
I do not know why.
Help.

[image]

[image]

=====update======

I was deleted IDE and IDE configuration files and reinstall IDE. It works well.. Maybe it is my mistake.
this is IDE configuration file path

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.jetbrains.intellij.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.jetbrains.intellij.plist.lockfile
~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea11
~/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea11
~/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea11
~/Library/Caches/com.jetbrains.intellij
~/Library/Logs/IntelliJIdea11
~/Library/Saved Application State/com.jetbrains.intellij.savedState
```

Comment: Stop running processes? Restart?

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-185077 /  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-20797 bug. Try version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion

Comment: @vikingsteve What process?

Comment: @Andrey Hello Thank you for answer. I tried update to version 2017.4, but it happend same..